# Do I need the .dat file when I place a visual studio database project under version-control

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, database-project

I have a visual studio 2008 database project that is under version control (git).  I am getting conflicts in the project_name.dat when I try to merge my branches.

So my questions ares:

1. What is the project_name.dat file?
2. Do I need it?  That is can I leave it out of my version control

Comment: What Visual Studio version? What project type? VS2005 C++, C# projects have no .dats IMO

Comment: @efraim you get .dat files when you have database projects in visual studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No , you shouldn't have it under sourcecontrol as it's autogenerated.

Comment: Build artefact ... fo' shure!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Offtopic but maybe useful:

You should configure your VCS so that special files and folders will be ignored during your commit.
I use Subversion in a Windows environment and the only thing to do is to put a file called *config* in %APPDATA%/subversion.

Inside it look like this:

> global-ignores = \bin \obj *.suo _ReSharper* *.resharper *.user *.ncb \Debug \Release